# Wireshark/Tshark json output in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm looking for a solution where I could send the json data that is produced on the console to a kafka topic. eg. `tshark -r "filename.pcap" -T json` to my kafka topic, or produce it on the same topic using `librdkafka`.

If somebody knows tshark internals where I could twitch it's module where the json is printed on the console to produce the json on my kafka topic instead. If only I could get to the point where the json is packed/made and then printed on the console should work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If only I could get to the point where the json is packed/made and then printed on the console should work. Thanks in advance.

The code that prints the JSON on the screen is in tshark.c [lines 4187-4206](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/wireshark-3.2.1/tshark.c#L4187-L4206) and [lines 3834-3837](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/wireshark-3.2.1/tshark.c#L3834-L3837)

```c
    if (print_details) {
      write_json_proto_tree(output_fields, print_dissections_none, TRUE,
                            protocolfilter, protocolfilter_flags,
                            edt, &cf->cinfo, node_children_grouper, &jdumper);
      return !ferror(stdout);
    }
```

and `write_json_proto_tree` is implemented in [epan/print.c:712](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/wireshark-3.2.1/epan/print.c#L712)